# Making search bar broader

Tags: css

I am trying to make the search bar broader on [this](http://rave.pk/) website but I am stuck on how to do so. Here is the code,

```
.searchform span .s {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    float: left;
    font: bold 13px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 135px;
}
```

Please guide me how to make the search area broader as depicted in the image below,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `.searchform span .s`, add:

```
width: calc(100% - 20px);
```

And then extend your background image on `span.searchfor` to fit.

Answer (score 0):

you have two style.css file, the `width: 100px`, override your `width: 135px`,beside the background for '.searchfor' is too small to cover 135px

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `span.searchfor` div has a background image

[image]

This is a fixed width image so when you try and make the input longer you are not seeing it.

A quick fix will be to take the colour from the image `#f9faf8` and apply it to the specific input and make it longer.

Adding this to your css file will fix the issue

```
.searchform span #sr {
    width:170px;
    background-color:#f9faf8;
}
```